# Sorting array in alphabetic order and displaying array values in table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I  have to print `NSMutableArray *lstAirports;`

my array of object it print all record in table view cell

I want to sort my cell value in alphabetical order.

how to do that please some help this code not given me display in alphabetical order

this is my code of controller class

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return app.lstAirports.count;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    airport *a=(airport*)[app.lstAirports objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"str:%@",a);
    cell.textLabel.text =a.Name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=a.Code;
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily sort a `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSSortDescriptor *nameSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
[lstAirports sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSort]];
```

Answer (score 1):

IN `viewWillAppear`

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
[app.lstAirports sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:aSortDescriptor]];
[aSortDescriptor release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to order the array from which you populate the table view, in this case `app.lstAirports`. [This](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/03/nsarray-sorting-using-selectors/) will teach you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your array using [`NSSortDescriptor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"key_name" ascending:YES];
[yourArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```