# What's the proper way to alphabetize a NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I found these code snippets from answers on Stack Overflow, neither elegantly solving my problem.

The first piece of code from ["Sorting array in alphabetic order…"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442778/sorting-array-in-alphabetic-order-and-displaying-array-values-in-table-view) gave no warnings but was followed by a crash.

```
NSSortDescriptor *nameSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSort]];
```

While the second piece of code generates a warning per use in my code but generates the results I want:

```
myMutableArray = [myMutableArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

So, my question is why does the second method work with the warning, "`Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray*' from incompatible type 'NSArray*'`"?

Comment: Documentation is your friend! [sortedArrayUsingSelector:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABBHAGJ) vs. [sortUsingSelector:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-BABCBFFC)

Comment: I tried assigning from `sortUsingSelector:` instead of treating it as a method, how embarrassing. xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to do an in-place sort of an NSMutableArray, you should use `sortUsingSelector:` rather than reassigning the result of `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` (which is declared to be a plain NSArray, not an NSMutableArray).

Comment: Thanks, I strayed from using this when I tried before because I had tried: `myMutableArray = [myMutableArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];` instead of using the actual `sortUsingSelector` method.